# JQuery with 2D array in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to get the value of the 2D array on this code using ng-repeat.

```
                   <div ng-repeat="n in status">
                        <div ng-repeat="x in n track by $index">
                            {{n}}
                        </div>  
                    </div>
```

my array is

```
$scope.status = [{1,2,4},{4,5,6,7},{8,9}];
```

right now i am getting the value of the array but with quotation and array bracket

```
["1","2","3"]
["4","5","6","7"]
["8","9"]
```

HELP PLEASE

Comment: Are you supposed to be printing X not N?

Comment: What is {1,2,4}? That's not a valid object, and it isn't an array. If we were using some other language I'd say maybe a tuple, but we're talking JavaScript here. I think what you want is [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ], [ 8, 9 ] ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to display `x`? `n` is an array just as you're seeing.

```
               <div ng-repeat="n in status">
                    <div ng-repeat="x in n track by $index">
                        {{x}}
                    </div>  
                </div>
```